# Proofs about Forbidden Minors

Tags: graph-theory

I am working on a problem which involves proving that a particular graph is a forbidden minor of the class of graphs that i am working on.

Now i read kuratowskis theorem for planarity but i still would like to know what other methods or approach can be taken in order to proceed with the proof.

Is it completely problem specific ? Or does there exist some general approach to solve this kind of problem ?

Comment: Restricted cycles and restricted complete bipartite subgraphs are pretty well studied. Lectures 9-10 here have the restricted bipartite bounds: http://math.mit.edu/~fox/MAT307.html. For cycles, try the lectures on the Bondy-Simonovits theorem here: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~dc340/Extremal-course.html.

Comment: Proving that a particular graph is a forbidden minor is usually easy. Show the graph does not have the relevant property, but that all of its single element deletions and contractions do have the property. This will depend entirely on the property. The trouble in excluded minor questions is always how to show that one's list of excluded minors is actually complete.

Comment: @GordonRoyle What if i follow this apporach:- First i prove that the family of graph does not contain the list of minors. Then I assume that even if graph are minor free, the property is violeted and try to bring out contradiction. Or should i look for a direct proof? what is done in general in these situations?